# Моделирование Классы Python помогите дополнить класс для пирамиды

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

В проекте по 3D-моделированию используются две фигуры — куб и пирамида. Для моделирования этих фигур используются соответствующие 2D-фигуры, а именно квадрат и треугольник. Вся поверхность 3D-фигуры может храниться в виде списка, например: для куба это будет [Square, Square, Square, Square, Square, Square].
Квадрат инициализируется длинами сторон, а треугольник — основанием и высотой. Каждая из 2D-фигур умеет находить свои периметр и площадь, а 3D-фигуры, в свою очередь, могут находить площадь своей поверхности.

Используя входные данные о фигурах и знания математики, реализуйте соответствующие классы и методы. Для базовых классов также реализуйте геттеры и сеттеры.

```
class Figure:
    figure_name = 'Фигура'

    def __init__(self, figure_name):
        self.figure_name = figure_name

    def show_name(self):
        print(self.figure_name)


class Square(Figure):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__('Квадрат')
        self.a = a

    def get_square(self):
        return self.a ** 2

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return 4 * self.a


class Triangle(Figure):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__('Треугольник')
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def get_square(self):
        return self.a * self.b * self.c

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c


class Cube(Figure):
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.f_name = 'cube'
        self.sq = (r ** 2) * 6
        self.pr = r * 12


class Pyramid(Figure):
    def __init__(self, r, a, b, c):
        self.f_name = 'pyramid'
        self.sq =
        self.pr = 


p = Pyramid(2, 4, 6, 8)
print(p.pr)

p = Cube(5)
print(p.pr)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Вот. Написал формулы для пирамиды и подправил формулы. Плюс добавил от себя некоторые моменты.

```
import math


class Square:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.figure_name = "Квадрат"
        self.a = a

    @property
    def square(self):
        return self.a ** 2

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return 4 * self.a


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, a, h):
        self.figure_name = "Треугольник"
        self.a = a
        self.h = h

    @property
    def square(self):
        return 0.5 * self.a * self.h

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.sqrt(self.h**2 + (self.a / 2)**2) + self.a


class Cube(Square):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.figure_name = 'Куб'

    @property
    def square(self):
        return 6 * super().square

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return 3 * super().perimeter


class Pyramid(Triangle, Square):
    def __init__(self, a, h):
        super().__init__(a, h)
        self.figure_name = 'Пирамида'

    @property
    def square(self):
        side_square = 4 * super().square
        base_square = self.a ** 2
        return side_square + base_square

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * super().perimeter + 2 * self.a


p = Pyramid(6, 4)
print(p.square)
print(p.perimeter)

p = Cube(5)
print(p.square)
print(p.perimeter)
```